# Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast java.lang.String to java.time.LocalDateTime] with root cause

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, java-8, spring-data-jpa

I am using Java 1.8 & SpringBoot 2.3.4.RELEASE. I am trying to use the AuditingEntityListener and @MappedSuperclass features to populate the created_date and updated_date timestamps.

But I am getting this Exception: **java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast java.lang.String to java.time.LocalDateTime**

I tried without @MappedSuperclass and it works.....but the created_date and updated_date fields are not getting populated.

Can anyone help me on this?

Here is the code snippet:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public abstract class AuditableEntity implements Serializable {

    @CreatedDate
    @Column(name = "created_ts",nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private LocalDateTime createdDate;

    @LastModifiedBy
    @Column(name = "updated_ts",nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime updatedDate;

    @CreatedBy
    @Column(name = "src_sys_cd",length = 15, updatable = false)
    private String source;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "record_version_nb", length = 20, nullable = false)
    private Long version;
}

----------------------------------
@Component
public class AuditorAwareImpl implements AuditorAware<String> {

  @Value("${customer.service.source.code}")
  private String auditor;

    @Override
    public Optional<String> getCurrentAuditor() {
        return Optional.of(auditor);
    }
}

----------------------------------
@Entity
@Setter
@Getter
@Builder
@Table(name = "customer_information")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CustomerEntity extends AuditableEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
}
```

Comment: Could it possibly be related to `@LastModifiedBy private LocalDateTime updatedDate`? I think you meant `@LastModifiedDate`

Comment: Yes you are right....I meant @LastModifiedDate.....I missed it. Thanks for identifying. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

`@LastModifiedBy` is used to set the current user when a modification happens. That is typically a `String` which can't be converted to anything date/time like and doesn't seem to be what you were looking for.
You should change this to:

```
@LastModifiedBy
@Column(name = "updated_ts",nullable = false)
private LocalDateTime updatedDate;


@LastModifiedDate
@Column(name = "updated_ts",nullable = false)
private LocalDateTime updatedDate;
```

Comment: thanks so much for identifying.....I looked at it so many times by thinking I kept @LastModifiedDate....so failed to notice. :)